# How to convert date from date picker in jqgrid from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: datepicker, jqgrid

I want a way to convert date from datepicker in jqgrid from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd.
Also I want to sort the date
How to do that?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. First of all you should write always which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Seconds, one have some **format of input data**, which can be **displayed** in jqGrid in another format based on the `formatoptions` of `formatter:"date"`. During *searching* or *editing* one can use jQuery UI or Bootstrap Datepicker to edit/enter the date **based on the options of datepicker**.

Comment: Which datepicker you use (jQuery UI, Bootstrap Datepicker or any other datepicker)? The options of datepicker depend on the format of **input data** and not from the options of `formatter: "date"`, which you use. Your question don't contains enough information to answer on it.